# configure interfaces in CISCO XRv 9000 ( kvm Environment)

Tags: cisco, kvm-virtualization

I have set up cisco XRv 9000 in  KVM Environment.I allocated 3 interfaces in xml file.

```
<interface type='bridge'>
  <mac address='52:f2:fe:00:00:30'/>
  <source bridge='br.vinet'/>
  <target dev='vn52f2fe000030'/>
  <model type='virtio'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x04' slot='0x01' function='0x0'/>
</interface>
<interface type='bridge'>
  <mac address='52:f2:ff:00:00:30'/>
  <source bridge='br.vsnet'/>
  <target dev='vn52f2ff000030'/>
  <model type='virtio'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x04' slot='0x02' function='0x0'/>
</interface>
<interface type='bridge'>
  <mac address='52:f2:fe:00:00:33'/>
  <source bridge='br.vsnet'/>
  <target dev='vn52f2fe000033'/>
  <model type='e1000'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x0a' function='0x0'/>
</interface>
```

But when i log and execute show interfaces i get below out put. seems like only one interface has up.

```
RP/0/RP0/CPU0:ios#show interfaces 
Mon Apr 22 04:58:00.248 UTC
Null0 is up, line protocol is up 
  Interface state transitions: 1
  Hardware is Null interface
  Internet address is Unknown
  MTU 1500 bytes, BW 0 Kbit
     reliability 255/255, txload Unknown, rxload Unknown
  Encapsulation Null,  loopback not set,
  Last link flapped 2d21h
  Last input never, output never
  Last clearing of "show interface" counters never
  5 minute input rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
  5 minute output rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
     0 packets input, 0 bytes, 0 total input drops
     0 drops for unrecognized upper-level protocol
     Received 0 broadcast packets, 0 multicast packets
     0 packets output, 0 bytes, 0 total output drops
     Output 0 broadcast packets, 0 multicast packets

MgmtEth0/RP0/CPU0/0 is administratively down, line protocol is administratively down 
  Interface state transitions: 0
  Hardware is Management Ethernet, address is 52f2.fe00.0033 (bia 52f2.fe00.0033)
  Internet address is Unknown
  MTU 1514 bytes, BW 1000000 Kbit (Max: 1000000 Kbit)
     reliability 255/255, txload 0/255, rxload 0/255
  Encapsulation ARPA,
  Full-duplex, 1000Mb/s, EX, link type is autonegotiation
  output flow control is off, input flow control is off
  loopback not set,
  Last input never, output never
  Last clearing of "show interface" counters never
  5 minute input rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
  5 minute output rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
     0 packets input, 0 bytes, 0 total input drops
     0 drops for unrecognized upper-level protocol
     Received 0 broadcast packets, 0 multicast packets
              0 runts, 0 giants, 0 throttles, 0 parity
     0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored, 0 abort
     0 packets output, 0 bytes, 0 total output drops
     Output 0 broadcast packets, 0 multicast packets
     0 output errors, 0 underruns, 0 applique, 0 resets
     0 output buffer failures, 0 output buffers swapped out
     0 carrier transitions
```

did i miss something or did i mis-configure ?

I am newbie to CISCO XRv 9000 :D

Comment: The interface show as administratively down, which means it has been issues the 'shutdown' command. Just use a 'no sh' on that interface.

Comment: ok, but why i dont see other interfaces ?

Comment: You did not provide any information on the connectivity of the interfaces. They will not show as 'up' even if you enable them if they are not actually connected to something (either physical or virtual).